# Wcf Data Service: How to handle case insensitive queries

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata, case-sensitive

I have a Wcf Data Service (it uses OData protocol) and using this query I want to get all countries, that stars with 'Ca' and this works:

> http://localhost/TestService/Data.svc/Countries?$filter=startswith(Name,
>   '**Ca**') eq true

But I'm unable to make it work with next query:

> http://localhost/TestService/Data.svc/Countries?$filter=startswith(Name,
>   '**ca**') eq true

This is auto-complete service for countries and I don't wont to make it case sensitive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use tolower (or toupper), for example:
/Countries?$filter=startswith(tolower(Name),tolower('Ca'))